# Polynom divisibility

Tags: matrices, polynomials, divisibility

I need to know, what is the best way to prove:

$(X-1)^4$ divides $X^{10}-2X^9+X^8-2X^6+4X^5-2X^4-X^2-2X+1$

Comment: Two possibilities : $1)$ Just apply polynomial division $2)$ calculate the first,second and third derivate and show that the polynomial and the derivates have root $1$

Comment: Show that the remainder of the division is $0$.

Comment: @Peter can u explain the second solution as an answer

Comment: I am working on an induction proof

Comment: Base case : Consider $p(x)=(x-a)\cdot q(x)+r(x)$ with $deg(r)=0$. This implies $p(a)=0$ if and only if $r(x)=0$ if and only if $x-a|p(x)$

Comment: Differentiating $\ p(x)=(x-a)\cdot q(x)+r(x)\ $ gives $\ p'(x)=q(x)+(x-a)\cdot q'(x)\ $. So, $\ p'(a)=q(a)\ $. So, $\ x-a|q(a)\ $ if  and only if $\ p'(a)=0\ $. This can be used to complete the induction step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(x-a)^k$ is a factor of a polynomial $p(x)$ if and only if $$p(a)=p'(a)=p''(a)=\cdots =p^{(k-1)}(a)=0$$

Comment: I suggest a small edit: The order of differentiation is [often set in parentheses](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/HigherOrderDerivatives.aspx) to avoid misinterpretation as exponentiation. Best regards,